# kendo custom command field does not works for me

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in my Html page all fields are working fine expect command field.

I need a button in command field. please check this code

```
columns: [{ field: 'Duration', title: 'Duration' },
                                     { field: 'Subject', title: 'Subject' },
                                     { field: 'EmailMessage', title: 'Email Message' },
                                     { field: 'SMSText', title: 'Message Text' },
                                    { command: { click: DeleteReminder, text: 'Delete' }, title: ' ', width: '140px' },

                           ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else is wrong with your code, the only issue that I see is if DeleteReminder is not defined at the moment of initialization. You can see a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/iYaNecov/2/edit). It uses the following column:

```
{command: { click: function(){alert('myFunction was invoked!')}, text: 'Delete' }, title: ' ', width: '140px' },
```